# How to update Activity's textview when returning from another Activity's RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

Hello (First of all excuse my English if something is wrong, it's not my first language), I'm developing an app with the IMDB API to keep up to date with your favorite series (no links or anything illegal).

I'm gonna focus on the two activities in which the problem is: The first Activity, ActivitySerieJson contains a recycled view filled with all the seasons in card view. Each card view contains season thumbnail, season number and the users completed view percentage:
[ActivitySerieJson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpjEK.png).

The second activity, ActivityTemporadaJSON contains another recyclerview, this one is filled with chapters name, thumbnail and an eye-shaped button that, when pressed, marks the chapter as seen on DB. The problem is that when I go back to previous activity the completed view percentage TextView is not being refreshed.
[ActivityTemporadaJSon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9CRc.png)

This is my code:

RecyclerAdapterTemporada

```
    public void bindPhoto(Temporada mtemporada, String idSerie, String tipo) {
        temporada = mtemporada;
        String Nombre = temporada.getNombreTemporada();

        if(Nombre.length() >= 25)
        {
            Nombre = Nombre.substring(0,22);
            Nombre = Nombre + "...";
        }

        AQuery androidAQuery=new AQuery(mItemImage.getContext());
        androidAQuery.id(mItemImage).image(temporada.getPoster(), true, true, 150,0);

        //Picasso.with(mItemImage.getContext()).load(mserie.getPoster()).into(mItemImage);

        mItemDate.setText(Nombre);
        mItemidTMDB.setText(idSerie);
        mItemNumTemp.setText(Integer.toString(temporada.getNumeroTemporada()));
        mItemNumEps.setText(Integer.toString(temporada.getNumeroEpisodios()));


        //THIS CODE SECTION CALCULATES PERCENTAGE
        if(tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("SQL"))
        {
            int porcen=1;
            int numEps = temporada.getNumeroEpisodios();
            if(numEps == 0){
                numEps = 1;
            }
            porcen = (temporada.getEpisodiosVsitos() * 100) / numEps;
            mNumEpsVistoVal.setText(Integer.toString(porcen) + "%");
        }
            else
        {
            mNumEpsVisto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mNumEpsVistoVal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

}

RecyclerAdapterEpisodio

```
public class RecyclerAdapterEpisodio extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterEpisodio.EpisodioHolder> {
private ArrayList<Episodio> mEpisodio;
private int IdSerie;
private RecyclerAdapterEpisodio miAdaptador;
private String Tipo;
private View v;


    //5
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /*Context context = itemView.getContext();
        Intent showPhotoIntent = new Intent(context, Pelicula.class);
        showPhotoIntent.putExtra(PHOTO_KEY, peli);
        context.startActivity(showPhotoIntent);*/
    }

    public void bindPhoto(final Episodio mEpisodio, final int mIdSerie, String tipo) {
        episodio = mEpisodio;

        if (tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("SQL")) {
            if(episodio.isVisto()){
                mBoton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ojoabierto);
            }else{
                mBoton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ojocerrado);
            }

            mBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (episodio.isVisto()) {
                        //mBoton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ojoabierto);
                        DBHelper mydb = new DBHelper(v.getContext());
                        mydb.CancelVerEpisodio(episodio.getIdEpisodio());
                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ojocerrado);
                        episodio.setVisto(false);

                    } else//else
                    {
                        //mBoton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ojocerrado);
                        DBHelper mydb = new DBHelper(v.getContext());
                        mydb.VerEpisodio(episodio.getIdEpisodio());
                        mBoton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ojoabierto);
                        episodio.setVisto(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            mBoton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Are you able to produce a smaller demonstration of the issue with less code? This is a lot for people to understand.

Comment: Im gonna edit the code section

Comment: since your view percentage is updated on db just update the value from db in your first activity `onResume`

Comment: View percentage is not stored on DB, only if chapter has been seen or not with a boolean. Percentage is calculated on RecyclerAdapterTemporada.

Answer (score 0):

in your fist activity do the loading inside OnResume(). so that when you comeback to the activity . onResume() method will be first called and you will get the updated data. This is when you have all your other block codes functioning well but you have problem with refreshing your page.

move your loading method from onCreate() to onResume() in the first activity